# Upload sketch in multiple arduinos

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

How do I upload sketches in multiple arduinos from one supervisor Arduino using UART , cd4051 for Rx and TX separately and reset pin low

Comment: That greatly depends on the actual type of Arduino board. Please describe, which Arduino boards you are trying to program and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @chrisl, tags are Uno, Nano

Comment: I am trying to upload program in 3 arduino nanos from 1 Arduino Uno by using cd4051 mux/demux for Rx and TX and setting reset to low when uploading to each one

Comment: it is not a trivial task. you have to implement the stk500 protocol or use a library which implements it.